# Parallel execution mutable lambda generator for std::generate_n

Tags: c++, lambda, parallel-processing, c++17

When using parallel execution for std::generate_n using a mutable lambda which has an initializer in its captures, is parallel access to initialized value thread-safe?

[MCVE]

```
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v(1000);
  std::generate_n(std::execution::par, v.data(), v.size(), [i = 0]() mutable { return i++; });

  return 0;
}
```

Is access to captured `i` thread-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is access to captured `i` thread-safe?

No. It's the responsibility of the client code to make sure no data races occur. What you can do is this (copied and customized from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t))

```
int i = 0;
std::mutex m;

std::generate_n(std::execution::par, v.data(), v.size(), [&]() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);    
    return i++; });
```

or, if you insist on the lambda capture together with the `mutable` keyword:

```
std::generate_n(std::execution::par, v.data(), v.size(),
    [i = 0, m = std::mutex()] () mutable  {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);    
        return i++; });
```

Note that as @Eric pointed out in the comments and @DmitryGordon in his answer, `std::generate_n` might copy the function object. This is problematic, as every copied instance has its own counter `i` that is incremented independently of the others. Also note that @rubenvb pointed out that copies of the function object in `std::generate_n` should even fail to compile. Hence, the first example is clearly preferable and maybe even the only doable one.

Comment: Is `std::ref` needed in your second example as the other answer suggests?

Comment: @Eric `std::ref` doesn't help in the second example, as the function objects is passed as a temporary. So when the `generate_n` template does copy the lambda multiple times, the second example won't work. I should add a note...

Comment: please notice that using locks/mutexes can greatly degrade the performance, so maybe there are other ways to generate your data? possibly without using any extra synchronised state?

Comment: @fen I absolutely agree that the synchronization in this example is an overkill. I assume that the scenario of generated values the OP has in mind is more complex than a counter and might justify this approach. Anyway, if you know another approach, an answer would definitely enrich this thread ;)

Comment: it would be good to know the final use case. plus we'd have to measure the performance, if the par version is that faster than seq version.

Comment: Won't the capture of mutex by value in the second example not work due to `generate_n` wanting to copy the lambda (which now has a member variable of type `std::mutex`?

Comment: @rubenvb True, it should fail to compile then. If the implementation does not make copies, the initial instance should be constructed in-place though and that should work out I guess.I updated the answer.

Comment: I think guaranteed copy elision in C++17 ensures the the lambda expression is initialized directly into the function argument - indeed, it compiles only with `--std=c++17` and onwards in GCC. So actually, `std::ref` is not needed here.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, let's have a look at generate_n's signature:

```
template< class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIt , class Size, class Generator >
ForwardIt generate_n(ExecutionPolicy&& policy, ForwardIt first, Size count, Generator g);
```

It's important that the last argument (it's your lambda) is passed **by value**. Also you don't know how it's passed internally in the implementation, so there may be some number of copies of your lambda and each of them will have it's own counter. I suppose it's not the intention.

There are several options to share the counter between instances:

1. Use std::ref on lambda:

   ```
   const auto func = [i = std::atomic<int>()]() mutable -> int {  
   return i++; };
   std::vector<int> v(1000);
   std::generate_n(std::execution::par, v.data(), v.size(), std::ref(func));
   ```
2. Share counter between instances of functor:

   ```
   std::atomic<int> i = 0;
   std::vector<int> v(1000);
   std::generate_n(std::execution::par, v.data(), v.size(), [&i]() -> int { return i++; });
   ```

Notice that in both cases I used std::atomic since you need to take care of synchronization yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much @dmitry, you made me aware of value passing for lambdas but I prefer lubgr answer since it's more pertinent to my question.